# How to stay DRY with validations in Domain objects and services vs validations in UI layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have searched for answers and even asked several questions on this subject, but haven't really found the right answer yet.  How do I expose validation methods in my POCO Domain objects and services to the UI layer?  Currently I am using web forms.

**For example, I have a the following domain object:**

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool IsValidEmail(string email) {}
    public bool IsValidName(string name) {}

    public bool IsValidPerson()
    {
        if (IsValidEmail(Email) && IsValidName(Name)) { return true; }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**and Domain Service:**

```
class PersonService
{

    private Person person;
    private PersonRepository pRepo;

    public PersonService()
    {
        person = new Person();
        pRepo = new PersonRepository();
    }

    public AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        if (p.IsValidEmail(p.Email) && p.IsValidName(p.Name) && !DoesEmailExistInDatabase(p.Email))
        { pRepo.Save(p); }
        else
        { throw new ArgumentException(); }
    }

    public GetPersonByEmail(string email)
    {
        if (person.IsValidEmail(Email))
        { pRepo.GetByEmail(email)); }
        else
        { throw new ArgumentException(); }
    }

    public bool DoesEmailExistInDatabase(string email) { //code if exists.. }
}
```

**and UI / Codebehind layer:**

**Get person by email**

```
string emailInput = EmailTextBox.Text;

PersonService pService = new PersonService();
Person p = new Person();

if(p.IsValidEmail(emailInput))
{
    Person myPerson = pService.GetPersonByEmail(emailInput);
}
else
{
    //give user error here...
}
```

1. Is it correct to create separate validation methods for each property in the domain object that may need validating?
2. Should those methods in domain object and service be static so I don't have to create the instance of person just to do the validation?
3. Should I expose the validations from the Person domain object in the Service so the user doesn't need to know where to look for them (as the reason that I have put some in service and some in POCO is really a implementation issue)?

4.Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re #1 - Yes (it's a valid approach) on the assumption that the domain object is best placed to "know" what correct input is.

Re #2 - Yes.

Re #3 - No harm in doing so, however, if you don't trust something external to the class to be able / responsible for the actual validation why would you then trust it to call the validation?

I would enforce the validation when the values are set, once you have "good data" in the object there should be no need to validate it later.  This leads to point #4...

Re #4 - The bonus in somehow providing / exposing the validation is that other parts of the system can use it; the classic example is at the UI where you can provide a better user experience by validating input as it's entered or submitted.

Another approach to the validation is to determine what good data looks like (in an overall view) - and define a bunch of rules for that that exist as a (separate) common domain level "service".  Validating input inside each domain object is good as you can change specific rules as the individual domain objects mature over time (you limit the impact of isolated changes) - the drawback is that you'll repeat a lot of rules.

A common service would fix this, a service would say "this is what a valid email address looks like" any all your domain objects would defer to the service to tell them what a good email address is.

The "trick" with this approach is to be careful how you name the validation methods - don't be too vague or ambiguous.  For example, you might find cases where most of your domain objects that have an email property use one "main" email validation method `ValidateGenericEmail()`, but you'll often have cases where other objects are special cases with special rules `ValidateCorporateEmail()`.  That's fine, add them to the validation service because that's the central place in the domain layer for managing those rules.

Your domain object can then still do everything you needed them to do before - except that you've pulled out the rules to a separate common place.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  When you say "I would enforce the validation when the values are set, once you have "good data" in the object there should be no need to validate it later. " - In the UI, I would usually validate the input parameters before even creating the object as the input might not even be a valid type.  Also, I have validations in the service layer that talk to the Repo because they need to query the db which is not allowed directly from the POCO.  My main thought was giving the consumer a single point to validate.

Comment: @Developr - "In the UI, I would usually validate the input parameters before even creating the object", that's fair enough. The way I'd normally do it is to use the property setters themselves as the main point of validation because there's no other way you can pass the information in (same applies to constructors - these would immediately 'set' the value using the publicly available setter - triggering the validation).

Comment: I started to add the validation on the setters, but I decided to abandon that as until the object is persisted, it should be able to be in a invalid state.  Also, with more complicated objects, throwing exceptions on the setters may lead to issues where the items must be set in a particular order to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep validation only on presentation layer and clean domain model from it. So domain model assumes that data has been already validated (and it is validated, isn't it?). Or do you have another source where data can come from?
 It would make your domain model much more pure and you would see its core. But it is decent to enforce some constraints at object's creation time by checking constructor arguments using guard clauses.

Comment: @xelibrion - what if you need to interact with a domain object on a different page, then you have to repeat the validation code all over again.  At least if you put basic validations on the object you can call them from a common place.  That way if the rules change later you can most likely just update the methods.

Comment: What about to put validation responsibility to viewmodel? You shouldn't use your domain object directly on your pages. You should convert it into viewmodel and interact with domain object through service

Comment: @xelibrion - what if i want to create a new person object in my code behind: Person p = new Person();  , then I can complete the properties and make a call the Service.Save(p); -- Is this not right?

Comment: "I'd keep validation only on presentation layer and clean domain model from it" No offense but isn't that a contradiction in terms? Beyond simple checks for *technically* bad input there's no way to check for bad *business* input without domain knowledge.  Unless you have the UI call out to a service for validation.

Comment: @Developr Yes, by my opinion it is not right. Let's imagine, you will want to publish WCF service, which will provide exactly same functionality, or move your application to ASP.NET MVC, which provide validation capabilities out of the box. Then you will have to duplicate this code. I would pass already validated PersonViewModel (just DTO, which has no knowledge about domain) to Service.Save() method.

Comment: @Adrian K I would like to separate validation (like simply checks for string length, email and etc) and business rules (like sum of order items) terms. Here is I'm talking about validation.

Comment: Here is good post from Ayende - http://ayende.com/blog/2278/input-validation-vs-business-rules-validation